# get next data-id selector js from current data-id element

Tags: html, ecmascript-6, intersection-observer

I have html that looks something like the below.

`dataId` below is the data-id that has just been scrolled over. At this point I want to get the closes `data-id` to this element. I have taken many approaches, unfortunately none of which are working.

```
<div data-id='12345'>
   <p>hello there</p>
</div>
<div class='break'>
   <p>no man's land</p>
</div>
<div data-id='5678'>
   <p>Go for it</p>
</div>
<div class='test'>
   <p>just a test</p>
</div>
<div class='example'>
   <p>example</p>
</div>
<div data-id='5789'>
   <p>Last one</p>
</div>
```

The js looks like this:

```
const firstDiv = $('div').attr('data-id["12345"]')
const nextDiv = firstDiv.next().attr('data-id');
// I am looking for the nextDiv to give me 5678
```

Comment: so what have you tried? what do you want/expect to happen?

Comment: @bowl0stu updated question

Comment: that makes it too specific. `$('div').attr('data-id["12345"]')` will only find `div`'s with that specific data-id.

Comment: try `const firstDiv = $('div[data-id]')`. this should allow it to find all `div`'s with a data-id attribute and (continuing on with your js) get the next `div`'s data-id